# Quais caracteres não posso utilizar para nomes de cookies?

Tags: navegador-de-internet, cookies, cross-browser

Estou desenvolvendo um novo sistema de autenticação, para diminuir a complexidade e aumentar a segurança. E estou desenvolvendo um sistema em que alguns cookies de autenticação terão nomes gerados randomicamente para cada sessão.

Minha duvida é a seguinte: Qual grupo de caracteres não devo utilizar para nomes de cookies? Ou qual grupo de caracteres posso utilizar para nomes de cookies? Não sei qual o menor conjunto...

*Gostaria de uma resposta independente de browser.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nos nomes de cookies você deve utilizar qualquer caracter ASCII "imprimível" (`!` até `~` e Unicode `\u0021` até `\u007e`), excluindo-se `,`, `;`,  e `=`.

Para os valores, a regra é quase a mesma, exceto que é possível usar o caracter `=` no valor.